# how to keep text left justified with image centered horizontally on page and text centered vertically to image

Tags: alignment

If I don't use float the text is aligned correctly vertically but not left justified.  If I do use float the text is aligned left by the vertical alignment is off

I also tried using flex but align-self doesn't seem to work:

```
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
border:solid 1px green;
}
p{align-self:start;}
```

```css
p{
float:left;
vertical-align:middle;
display:inline-block;
}

img{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;}

div{
text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<p>some text</p>
<img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/150x30">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
border:solid 1px green;
}

#x{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<p>some text</p>
<img src ="https://via.placeholder.com/150x30">
<p id='x'>some text</p>
</div>
```